# Split cells into two rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this:

[image]

and would like to split those three cells into two rows without affecting the rest of the spreadsheet.

Something like this:

[image]

But this was done by adding another row and then merging the cells next to it

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't selectively add rows to certain columns.  You can add a row to all the columns like you did and adjust the rest.  You can automate the process with VBA.

Comment: @wbeard52 I have no idea what VBA is, could you show me how to do that with VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the only thing you can do. You can't have half a row, at least if you need both halves to be separately accessible to formulas and so on.

If you don't actually need two independent entries, but you want to put two things in the cell, you can press Alt+Enter during entry to add a newline into the cell contents.

But that's only going to help you if you only need plain text in the cells and you don't need to use them in a formula anywhere else. Otherwise, you're going to have to create an extra row and merge the cells you don't want to be doubled. (If it's just for appearance, you can probably get away with just putting a white border between them.)